# OctoPosh function works with literal but not with params (string+num)

Tags: powershell

I'm calling the cmdlet `Get-OctopusEnvironment`: 
https://octoposh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmdlets/get-octopusenvironment/#parameters from OctoPosh. The call works if I enter a literal like ENV1. (This is a sample value, obviously you need to enter a value that exists as a environment on the Octopus server)

However, I'm using a script with params and the `$env` and `$num` need to be combined to identify the environment that I wish to target.

I tried:

1. Calling it in another session
2. Setting the `$env` and `$num` separately and then calling the method
3. Calling the function with the literal value - which always works.

```bsh
Param(
    [string]$env,
    [string]$num
)

Import-Module Octoposh

Set-OctopusConnectionInfo (Call details hidden)

$result = Get-OctopusEnvironment -EnvironmentName $env+$num

$result
```

Output:

```
<pre>
Name        : ENV1
Id          : Environments-1
Machines    : {some server}
Deployments : {some octopus projects}
Resource    : Octopus.Client.Model.EnvironmentResource
</pre>
```

UPDATE: this seems to work fine for some reason. And it solves my problem... GetEnvironment basically just does the same as I wanted to. It combines the params `$env+$num` and returns them.

```
if($env -eq "DEV" -or $env -eq "INT")
{
     Set-OctopusConnectionInfo 

      $envName = .\GetEnvironment.ps1 $env $num

      $result = Get-OctopusEnvironment -EnvironmentName $envName
 }
```

Comment: Try and put brackets around `$env+$num`, so the strings get combined first and the `-EnvironmentName` parameter received the concatenated result as one single string.

Comment: What Theo said. Also, `env` is a prefix used for accessing environment variables in PowerShell (e.g. `$env:USERNAME`), so I would recommend to avoid using it as a variable/parameter name, even if it works.